# How to modify shapes created under "Edit" of main menu

Tags: qgis

In my QGIS 3.4.4 main menu (not in a layout) I noted, under "Edit", an "Add Rectangle" option. So I tried it, and succeeded in creating a rectangle. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out any way to edit it (color, size, etc.); nor to delete it, or do anything else with it. Can someone please give me a clue about this?

Answer (score 3):

The questions is very broad, so instead of copying everything from the user manual, I'll leave you with the relevant links:

- [Editing geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#vertex-tool)
- [Editing attributes](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#editing-attribute-values)

Comment: Thank you, but those links seem to address shapes created in one of the layers of a map. The rectangle I made does not seem to be in any of my layers. I can turn off all of the layers, and the rectangle remains. I guess I'm confused about something basic here...

Comment: Now suddenly it seems to be working as expected. I don't know why it started working or why it did not before...